# Data Transfer between two BigQuery Projects using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have created two projects on Google Cloud Platform say project1 and project2. Project1 has a bigquery dataset named dataset1 which contains a table named table1 which has some contents. Project2 has a bigquery dataset named dataset2 which contains a table named table2 which is empty. I need a python code that will copy/import the table1 and export/copy it to table2 which was initially empty using Google Cloud Functions tool.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to use Cloud Functions for this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Understand how to use Python to send a query to BigQuery following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#running_queries).
2. The query to "copy/import the table1 and export/copy it to table2" you will need is (assuming table2 has exactly same schema as table1):

```
INSERT INTO project2.dataset2.table2 
SELECT * FROM project1.dataset1.table1;
```

Comment: Inserting a query job with `configuration.query.destination_table = project2.dataset2.table2` and `configuration.query.write_disposition = WRITE_EMPTY` (which is the default value) would also work, assuming the schemas are compatible: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job

Comment: More things can be done with a query though. Like [MERGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) statement to incrementally copy table.

Comment: Note that a query will have the cost of a full table scan, and doing a copy through API will be free. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Answer (score 1):

Find Python code to copy a table here:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table

The code is:

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()

source_dataset = client.dataset("samples", project="bigquery-public-data")
source_table_ref = source_dataset.table("shakespeare")

# dataset_id = 'my_dataset'
dest_table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table("destination_table")

job = client.copy_table(
    source_table_ref,
    dest_table_ref,
    # Location must match that of the source and destination tables.
    location="US",
)  # API request

job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

assert job.state == "DONE"
dest_table = client.get_table(dest_table_ref)  # API request
assert dest_table.num_rows > 0
```

There's another answer to that question that shows you can do it with `INSERT INTO *`, but that operation will have the cost of a full table scan - vs free with this one.

(I normally use `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT INTO` because they are more convenient tho)

Comment: Thanks! But what if one "client" has access to source dataset and another "client" has access to the destination. i.e. authenticating both with the service account.